# Extract text based on keywords in R

Tags: r, twitter

I have a df `twitter` containing tweets from twitter for a certain period of time,  I want to filter tweets  that  related to COVID-19 according to the keywords df `cov-key` that contain 150 keywords.

I use the following code to filter tweet:

```
twitter_cov<-twitter[str_detect(twitter$content,cov_key$keywords),]
```

However, the relationship between the keywords in the `cov-key` seems like the "&" rather than the "|" relationship.SO how to filter tweets from the `twitter` as long as it contains any one keyword in the `cov-key`

Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
pat <- paste0(cov_key$keywords, collapse = "|")

twitter_cov <- twitter %>% 
  filter(str_detect(content, pat))
```

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I wrote a function for this and put it in a package:

```r
library(dplyr)
# make some random test data
test <- tibble(text = stringi::stri_rand_lipsum(10))
# make a list of keywords
keywords <- c("orci", "velit", "morbi")

# add information which keyword(s) is/are present
test_new <- test %>% 
  mutate(keyword = LexisNexisTools::lnt_lookup(test$text, pattern = keywords))
test_new
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>    text                                                                 keyword 
#>    <chr>                                                                <list>  
#>  1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nostra ridiculus et, magna erat bibendu… <chr [2…
#>  2 Donec non eget, convallis sodales est mus quam non et nulla phasell… <chr [2…
#>  3 Magna eros sed praesent arcu, fermentum. Duis a quam, lectus dapibu… <NULL>  
#>  4 Velit erat sed quis ac molestie, pellentesque metus eu nec, curabit… <chr [1…
#>  5 Ipsum convallis vehicula euismod vel et in, nec, iaculis, non phare… <NULL>  
#>  6 Purus consectetur inceptos efficitur aenean cubilia lorem ipsum feu… <chr [1…
#>  7 Dictum eleifend in sed quam odio justo non aliquet porttitor lacini… <NULL>  
#>  8 Gravida ac, et taciti. Justo ut tincidunt ad molestie sed ad sed na… <chr [1…
#>  9 Magnis sed nulla turpis. Elit blandit natoque nulla turpis lorem co… <NULL>  
#> 10 Imperdiet eget cursus quam elit sagittis. Ex nisl in odio finibus q… <chr [1…
```

Since the `keyword` colum is a list you have to use `sapply` to remove `NULL` entries:

```r
test_new %>% 
  filter(!sapply(keyword, is.null))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   text                                                                  keyword 
#>   <chr>                                                                 <list>  
#> 1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nostra ridiculus et, magna erat bibendum… <chr [2…
#> 2 Donec non eget, convallis sodales est mus quam non et nulla phasellu… <chr [2…
#> 3 Velit erat sed quis ac molestie, pellentesque metus eu nec, curabitu… <chr [1…
#> 4 Purus consectetur inceptos efficitur aenean cubilia lorem ipsum feug… <chr [1…
#> 5 Gravida ac, et taciti. Justo ut tincidunt ad molestie sed ad sed nat… <chr [1…
#> 6 Imperdiet eget cursus quam elit sagittis. Ex nisl in odio finibus qu… <chr [1…
```

The advantage is that you can store the data with keywords and if you decide later on to only keep tweets with some of your keywords and discard other keywords, the process is super fast.